# Error in connecting App to App using Bluetooth in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth, socketexception

I Created a Game in which I am trying to Communicate game to game over Bluetooth in Windows phone 8. and i tried the same way in the [Bluetooth app to app sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Bluetooth-app-to-app-sample-890f8303)

I got the Peerlist of the devices around the host/Server device.
But when i try to connect it. It shows an errors this

[image]

Comment: Old thread but this is what resolved my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833507/windows-phone-8-bluetooth-error-hresult-0x8007271d