# How to check status of bluetooth in Windows Runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

There are some odd ways, like checking for pair devices [and catching exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833507/windows-phone-8-bluetooth-error-hresult-0x8007271d) to see it if is on or not.

```
if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x8007048F)
{
   var result = MessageBox.Show("Bluetooth is turned off.\nTo see the current Bluetooth settings tap 'ok'", "Bluetooth Off", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
}
```

But I see there is a new [`BluetoothConnectionStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothconnectionstatus%28v=win.10%29.aspx) api but don't know how to use it.

How to check bluetooth status in Windows Phone Runtime apps?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably something like this:

```
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
// look for any paired device
PeerFinder.AllowBluetooth = true;
// start looking for BT devices
PeerFinder.Start();
PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
// get the list of paired devices
var peers = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
var peer = peers.First(p => p.DisplayName.Contains("my_bt_device_name"));

var bt = await BluetoothDevice.FromHostNameAsync(peer.HostName);
if (bt.ConnectionStatus == BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected)
{
    // My device is connected
}
```

Comment: BluetoothDevice hasn't a constructor, is static.

Comment: Oh, i see now. It's not static. It just doesn't have a ctor. It requires you pick a specific device using `FromHostNameAsync` or `FromBluetoothAddressAsync`. You can use the `PeerFinder` API to get that information

Comment: Thanks. seems catching the exception is the only way to know. it will throw exception if bluetooth is off, also, my bluetooth isn't listed in peers, only other devices.