# How to determine if Bluetooth is turned on on Windows Phone 8(.1)

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth

My question is pretty much asked in the title. Is there a way how to find out programatically whether the **bluetooth device** on WP 8 is **turned on**? I know you can just start **discovery service** and if you do not get any peers, you assume BT is turned off. However, I am just dismayed that there is no straightforward property for this or maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using the `BluetoothConnectionStatus`, to check the indication whether the `Bluetooth` is turned on?

Check these out:

[Windows Phone 8 Bluetooth Error HRESULT: 0x8007271D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833507/)

[How to check status of bluetooth in Windows Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545233/)

Comment: For now, I am using the mentioned HRESULT. It works, because if you are trying to start discovery service and BT is turned off it returns this exception. I just wanted simple bool property. Seems like a logical thing to me to have it.

As for the `BluetoothConnectionStatus` I thought it indicates whether you are connected to other device. It is not exactly what I want.

Comment: I accepted this answer, because the exception really is the only answer in WP right now.